# What is Xwayland? What if I remove it from Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, xorg, uninstall, 22.04

Xwayland seems new in Ubuntu 22.04. What is it? Is removing it safe?

Answer (score 34):

Starting from Ubuntu 21.10, Ubuntu again by default uses Wayland as its display manager (it once did before for 17.10, but quickly reverted back to Xorg for 18.04 LTS). Xwayland is an Xorg emulation layer of Wayland. It provides applications access to Xorg libraries, allowing to run programs that only can run on Xorg.

From a security point of view, it is certainly "safe" to remove it, because it precludes any use of less secure Xorg libraries. Functionally, though, you will not be able to run any applications that do not yet support Wayland, such as Gimp. A few of the older system tools in Ubuntu, e.g. Software Updater and Software & Updates. Afaik, all graphical software and tools that come with the default Ubuntu desktop natively run on Wayland.

Comment: It would be better to mention that Wayland is the default window system in Ubuntu 22.04, otherwise it's not obvious why one would need Xorg emulation. Ubuntu 20.04 uses Xorg by default, so it's a change.

Comment: Thanks. That would indeed give more context to the answer, so I added this information.

Answer (score 21):

Xwayland is an X server for running X clients under Wayland. Xwayland is installed by default in Ubuntu 22.04, so you shouldn't try to uninstall it.

This package provides an X server running on top of wayland, using wayland input devices for input and forwarding either the root window or individual top-level windows as wayland surfaces.

Comment: ‘installed by default’ is not a particularly good argument for not removing something. _Lots_ of things installed by default on Ubuntu are never actually used by most users and can generally be removed safely. A better argument here is that Ubuntu 22.04 uses Wayland by default, and many applications do not have native support for it yet and do not properly list XWayland as a dependency in their package metadata, so uninstalling it will likely cause many applications to simply not work for no apparent reason.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn That's quite correct but someone else already posted that in another answer, so I'm not going to repeat it except to acknowledge that I agree that it is a better argument for not uninstalling xwayland, however I've also learned the hard way not to install packages that are installed in Ubuntu by default.

Comment: Just because the answer is a "better" argument doesn't mean that yours is a "good" argument. In fact it isn't an argument at all: the decision whether to uninstall something or not has nothing to do with whether it is installed by default. What matters is whether you or the OS *needs* that package or not. This answer could also mislead people into thinking they shouldn't e.g. uninstall LibreOffice, Firefox, Thunderbird, or any other of the numerous packages that there is no need to keep unless you use them.

Comment: Indeed, the fact that there exist multiple different editions (Server v Desktop) and flavours (Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc.) of Ubuntu, all with different sets of default installed packages, shows definitively that some packages can be safely removed depending on what you use your OS for. Perhaps the answer could be improved by saying something along the lines of "you shouldn't uninstall default installed packages unless you know what you are doing".

Comment: Apparently Ubuntu-MATE 22.04 does NOT support Wayland, according to Martin Wimpress ("wimpy"), a project leader with the Ubuntu-MATE community. See https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/25318/8

Answer (score 1):

then it would seem that stoping it in systems monitor
you would perceive what applications are dependent on Xwayland

i am not going to do this i have had enough of bringing back system
with timeshift
which is a brillent program saved me a number of times